# How can i write this group by query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

This is the query for sql

```
SELECT type ,SUM(amount) FROM CustomerPayment GROUP BY type
```

How can i write this in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same in hql:

`select c.type, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c group by c.type`

Comment: above code gives org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: c [select c.type, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c group by c.type]
 at org.hibernate.hql.classic.FromParser.token(FromParser.java:106) error

Comment: Post the code for `CustomerPayment` entity. I assumed that you have the amount and type columns mapped to the coresponding fields.

Comment: yeah i have them in my table

Comment: <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="CODE" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="date" type="string">
            <column name="DATE" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="amount" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="AMOUNT" precision="12" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="string">
            <column name="TYPE" length="10" />
        </property>

Comment: I believe your entity is not mapped correctly in Hibernate, can you execute `from CustomerPayment` query?

Comment: The fields mapping seems to be OK. But the class name? Can you post the xml config. with the class to table mapping?